# Passing external configuration / parameters to a Meteor *mobile* build?

Tags: javascript, cordova, meteor

I need to be able to pass configuration values / parameters or similar to a Meteor *mobile* build - so that these values may be accessible to the Meteor code running on the device.

I was looking for something similar to how a settings file is passed to a Meteor server deploy (via `meteor --settings settings.json`) but for a mobile build.

I thought meteor's mobile-config.js may have been a possibility but it's limited to certain inputs and doesn't appear to be available to the app after it's built.

Even the ability to package up a text-file during the build would be useful as it could then be read using something like https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you need to switch based on environment variables in your **mobile-config.js** file, like this:

```
if (this.process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {

  // production 

} else {

  // local
}
```

> --mobile-settings

```
$ NODE_ENV=production 
$ meteor build ../app --server http://<app-server> --mobile-settings settings.json
```

Comment: I was unaware of the '--mobile-settings' option - thanks for that. However, I tried it out and saw some weird behaviour. Basically, I deployed the app to the server (without the mobile-settings file), built the mobile app (with the mobile-settings), but when I ran the app on a device the settings value appeared on screen for a second, but then the app re-loaded and the setting disappeared. I assume this is because the app was refreshed from the server... where the setting did not exist? This seems weird to me - and doesn't seem to be a workable solution.

Comment: I've submitted a separate question for the issue above (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32007348/meteor-mobile-settings-being-overriden-by-server-values). I'll leave this one open for the time being. If I can sort out the overridden mobile settings, then that will be a suitable solution and I'll close this question off.